# Getting site took too long error for Jenkins server from AWS EC2 instance

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops

Yesterday when I set up AWS and jenkins I created my first job in jenkins server from AWS linux system. Then I stopped the instance and today I started the instance and when trying to connect to http://my-public-ip:8080 it is showing ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I have added 8080 in inbound ip address as well. I have tried both the ip addresses(the one I used yesterday and the one I got today). Please help me.

Please find the instance inbound screenshot here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I24J8.png)

Comment: Have you checked your AWS security groups? Firewalls in the Instance itself?

Comment: I tried disabling the firewall but couldn't do so, from other computer I can access the jenkins dashboard by hitting the aws ip address and 8080, but happening only for my laptop.

Comment: I used tunneling with localhost from PuTTy app and that's how I'm using currently. Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to Jenkins by address - "your_new_ip:8080/manage/configure" - Jenkins location and change yesterday_ip to your_new_ip.

You have to do it every time when ip changed